# Shortest way to modify strings in a comma separated list, in PHP

Tags: php

If I want to modify a comma separated list like this:

```
$foo = "2, 4, 33, 25, 66"
```

to become

```
$foo = "'1-2', '1-4', '1-33', '1-25', '1-66'"
```

What would be the fastest and most efficient way to achieve that in PHP?

**EDIT:**
I have tried this, but looking for a better way:

```
$foo = "2, 4, 33, 25, 66";
$bar = implode("', '1-",explode(",",$foo));
$foo = "'1-". $bar ."'";
```

Comment: You need to first explode string and then use loop.

Comment: all are using almost the same logic..  i wan't to see a regex.. :)

Comment: @roullie, as requested, regex solution provided below.

Comment: It would be great if you showed some effort, rather than just expecting others to write code for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$foo = "2, 4, 33, 25, 66";
echo preg_replace("/(\d+)(,?)/", "'1-$1'$2", $foo );
```

As requested by @roullie, here's a fast regex solution.  In the regex, `\d+` matches 1 or more digits. `,?` matches 0 or 1 comma (the last item does not have a common so I must match on 0 or 1.

Comment: heads up for using `regex`.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Shortest code:

```
implode(", ", array_map(function($item) {
    return "'1-{trim($item)}'";
}, explode(",", $foo));
```

Basically you split the string by comma, and you map the numbers to the `1-$number'` format, not forgetting to trim the exploded values, and then join them back. This is also the fastest code, as the amount of interpreted `PHP` code is minimum.

If you're sure that all items in the initial strings are separated by comma+space, then you can explode by that string, and leave the `trim()` out:

```
implode(", ", array_map(function($item) {
    return "'1-$item'";
}, explode(", ", $foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

`$foo = implode(", ", array_map(function($v) {return "1-".$v}, explode(", ", $foo)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
$foo = "2, 4, 33, 25, 66";
$new_foo = implode("', '1-",explode(",",$foo));
echo "'1-".$new_foo."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

First move it to array and append 1- to each number.

```
values[] = array_explode(",",$foo);
unset($foo);
foreach($values as $value)
{
      $value = '1-'.$value;
      $foo[] = $value;
}
```